# Python/ Pandas: calculate 1. minimum, 2. max of columns to left of minimum and 3. max of columns to right of minimum

Tags: python, pandas

This is a continuation of [Python/ Pandas: Finding a left and right max](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63876495/python-pandas-finding-a-left-and-right-max)

I have a dataframe, with timelines of data. Here is an example:

```
idx Q12000      Q22000      Q32000      Q42000      Q12001      Q22001      Q32001     Q42001      Q12002      Q22002      Q32002      Q42002

0   4085280.0   4114911.0   4108089.0   4111713.0   4055699.0   4076430.0   4043219.0  4039370.0   4201158.0   4243119.0   4231823.0   4254681.0
1   21226.0     21566.0     21804.0     22072.0     21924.0     23232.0     22748.0    22258.0     22614.0     22204.0     22500.0     22660.0     
2   96400.0     102000.0    98604.0     97086.0     96354.0     103054.0    97824.0    95958.0     115938.0    123064.0    120406.0    120648.0   
3   23820.0     24116.0     24186.0     23726.0     23504.0     23574.0     23162.0    23078.0     22306.0     22334.0     22152.0     22080.0     
4   7838.0      7906.0      7714.0      7676.0      7480.0      7520.0      7102.0     6722.0      8324.0      8166.0      8208.0      8326.0
```

To do my analysis I need to calculate the following values for each row:

- **nadir**: the lowest point (min)
- **nadir_qtr**: the quarter at which the nadir happens
- **pre-peak**: the highest point *before* the nadir
- **pre-peak_qtr**: the quarter at which the pre-peak happens
- **post-peak**: the highest point *after* the nadir
- **post-peak_qtr**: the quarter at which the post-peak happens

With the help from my last post, I used the below helper functions:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

def calc_nadir(s):
    assert isinstance(s, pd.Series)
    return s.min()

def calc_nadir_qtr(s):
    return s.argmin()

def calc_pre_peak(s):
    return s[ : s.argmin()].max()

def calc_pre_peak_quarter(s):
    try:
        qtr = s[ : s.argmin()].argmax()
    except:
        qtr = None
    return qtr

def calc_post_peak(s):
    return s[s.argmin() : ].max()

def calc_post_peak_qtr(s):
    return s[s.argmin() : ].argmax() + s.argmin()

nadir = df.apply(lambda x: calc_nadir(x), axis=1).rename('nadir')
nadir_qtr = df.apply(lambda x: calc_nadir_qtr(x), axis=1).rename('nadir_qtr')

pre_peak = df.apply(lambda x: calc_pre_peak(x), axis=1).rename('pre_peak')
pre_peak_qtr = df.apply(lambda x: calc_pre_peak_quarter(x), axis=1).rename('pre_peak_qtr')

post_peak = df.apply(lambda x: calc_post_peak(x), axis=1).rename('post_peak')
post_peak_qtr = df.apply(lambda x: calc_post_peak_qtr(x), axis=1).rename('post_peak_qtr')

results = pd.concat([nadir, nadir_qtr, pre_peak, pre_peak_qtr, 
                     post_peak, post_peak_qtr], axis=1)
print(results)

       nadir  nadir_qtr   pre_peak  pre_peak_qtr  post_peak  post_peak_qtr
0  4039370.0          7  4114911.0           1.0  4254681.0             11
1    21226.0          0        NaN           NaN    23232.0              5
2    95958.0          7   103054.0           5.0   123064.0              9
3    22080.0         11    24186.0           2.0    22080.0             11
4     6722.0          7     7906.0           1.0     8326.0             11
```

The trouble I'm having is the second line. Having the nadir as the first column is not meaningful, so I altered the above code to only get the nadir after the first few columns.

```
nadir = df.iloc[:,6:].apply(lambda x: calc_nadir(x), axis=1).rename('nadir')
nadir_qtr = df.iloc[:,6:].apply(lambda x: calc_nadir_qtr(x), axis=1).rename('nadir_qtr')
```

That seems to work well enough. But I'm stuck on how to get the pre-peak to replace the NaNs.

I've tried iterating through the rows, but no luck. Still getting Nans in the exact same spots.

```
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if not row['pre_peak']:
            slice = row['nadir_qtr'][index]
            row['pre_peak'] = row.iloc[1:slice].max(axis=0)
```

Any advice appreciated

Comment: I am also open to editing the title of this post. I don't feel that this is the best way to describe it for others to find.

Comment: Your problem is in your data. When `nadir_qtr` is 0, there is no data before it, and therefore no `pre-peak`.

Comment: that's why i shifted the nadir to only count after the sixth quarter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.iloc[:1,:]` to only select after the first column, and use a bunch of pandas methods like `.min`, `.max`, `idxmin`, `idxmax` and others:

```
df['nadir'] = df.iloc[:,1:].min(axis=1)
df['nadir_qtr'] = df.iloc[:,1:].idxmin(axis=1).apply(lambda x: df.columns.get_loc(x))
df['new'] = [df.iloc[i].values for i in df.index]
df['pre_peak'] = df.apply(lambda x: max(x['new'][0:x['nadir_qtr']]), axis=1)
df['post_peak'] = df.apply(lambda x: max(x['new'][x['nadir_qtr']:]), axis=1)
df['pre_peak_qtr'] = pd.Series([s[i] for i, s in zip(df.index, df['pre_peak'].apply(
    lambda x: [i for i in (df.iloc[:,0:-6] == x)
               .idxmax(axis=1)]))]).apply(lambda x: df.columns.get_loc(x))
df['post_peak_qtr'] = pd.Series([s[i] for i, s in zip(df.index, df['post_peak'].apply(
    lambda x: [i for i in (df.iloc[:,0:-6] == x)
               .idxmax(axis=1)]))]).apply(lambda x: df.columns.get_loc(x))
df_new = df[['nadir', 'nadir_qtr', 'pre_peak', 'pre_peak_qtr', 'post_peak', 'post_peak_qtr']]
df_new
Out[1]: 
         nadir  nadir_qtr   pre_peak  pre_peak_qtr  post_peak  post_peak_qtr
idx                                                                         
0    4039370.0          7  4114911.0             1  4254681.0             11
1      21566.0          1    21226.0             0    23232.0              5
2      95958.0          7   103054.0             5   123064.0              9
3      22080.0         11    24186.0             2    22080.0             11
4       6722.0          7     7906.0             1     8326.0             11
```